# Django include template no data

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to include a file, into my base.html
Inside the base, inn the base.html

```
{% block content %}

{% include "something.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

But nothing shows up from the included file, and I have tried to have blocks inn the something.html

```
{% block content %}
something something inside the something.html
{% endblock %}
```

I have also tried without using blocks, but nothing.

Comment: You forgot a closing double quote (`"`) in the `{% include "something.html" %}` tag.

Comment: Updated it, i just forgot it in the question, not in template

Comment: Does your "parent" template defined the `content` block?

Comment: all other templates that extends the base have block content yes

Comment: and you do not use `{% block ... %}`s, etc. in the `something.html`.

Comment: I use block content there also, but regardless there is no error, and no content from the included html

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is

`base.html`

```
{% block content %}

{% include "something.html" %}

{% endblock %}
```

`something.html`

```
<div>my content in something</div>
```

If you you put a `block` statement in the included template it will not show up.

More details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: I tried with and without, still does not show up

Comment: Are they in the same directory? The include statement is relative to your TEMPLATE_ROOT

Answer (score 0):

whatyouwanttoinclude.html

```
<body>
............
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
...........
</body>
```

whereyouwanttoinclude.html

```
{% extends 'whatyouwanttoinclude.html' %}
{% block content %}
    some html here
{% endblock content %}
```

Now when you render the template whereyouwanttoinclude.html, it will also show the contents of whatyouwanttoinclude.html